# Examples of reductive algebraic groups that aren't written in the form of a closed subgroup of $\text{GL}(V)$.

Tags: soft-question, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let us remain over $\Bbb C$.

Any affine algebraic group is isomorphic to a closed algebraic subgroup of $\text{GL}(V)$ for some representation space $V$. In particular this holds for the subclass of affine algebraic groups that are reductive.

What are some examples of reductive algebraic groups that are not *given* in the form of a subgroup of $\text{GL}(V)$?

**Motivation:** I just want to do some small explicit examples of embedding these groups into some $\text{GL}(V)$, just so I know what they look like concretely. (I know how to do it 'abstractly')

Comment: How about $PGL(V)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\mathrm{PGL}_n(k)$ is reductive.  It is given as the quotient of $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ by scalar matrices, i.e., matrices of the form $\lambda I$ where $\lambda \in k$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: No way to embed it into $GL_n(k)$ ?

Comment: @reuns You can't embed $\mathrm{PGL}_n(k)$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$, but you can embed it into $\mathrm{GL}_m(k)$ for some larger $m$.

Comment: Just curious, how would you do it for $n=2$ ?

Comment: You're looking for an injection $\mathrm{PGL}_n(k) \to \mathrm{GL}_m(k)$, or in other words a faithful representation, and then you'll need to check that the image is closed.  The adjoint representation on the lie algebra probably works, with maybe some conditions on $k$?  It's been a while since I've thought about these things.

Comment: Say for $k = \mathbb{C}$ you identity $\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ with ( a sub Lie algebra of) $\mathfrak{gl}_m$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G = PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: It's proved in generality (in a constructive way) in Humphreys Linear Algebraic Groups, Theorem 8.6 [that such a thing is possible]. That constructive way is what I was wanting to explore. I will try this out as soon as I have time, and edit this community wiki, for $n=2$ (atleast).